# How do I get rid of the `Warning: <Text /> is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.` warning when running jest tests

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

**My test looks like this**

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme"
import * as React from "react"
import { Text } from "react-native"

import { StatusCircle } from "../StatusCircle"

it("renders correctly", () => {
    const circle = shallow(<StatusCircle nr={1} total={10} />)
    expect(circle.find(Text).render().text()).toEqual("1/10")
    expect(circle).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

**Running the test**

```
 PASS  src/components/__tests__/StatusCircle.tsx
  ● Console

    console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
      Warning: <Text /> is using uppercase HTML. 
               Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.
    console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
      Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `accessible`.
```

It's a React Native app. The text elements are written in capital letters.
How do I tell Jest or Enzyme that it should not throw any error messages for this?

Answer (score 2):

This has been addressed as an issue on the Jest Github repo, but it seems to be expected behaviour. The docs do explain possible workarounds, see [this link](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#snapshot-testing-with-mocks-enzyme-and-react-16) for more information.

You basically have 3 options:

1. Use react-test-renderer
2. Render as text: **jest.mock('./StatusCircle', () => () => 'StatusCircle');**
3. Render as custom element: **jest.mock('./StatusCircle', () => 'status-circle');**